# QT can't find right OpenGL api to use

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, opengl-es-2.0

My QT 5.8 based code fails to run any OpenGl command on some windows machines. Seems like it cant find the right rendering API.
Here is relative part of the terminal log.

```
qt.qpa.gl: QWindowsIntegration::createPlatformOpenGLContext QSurfaceFormat(version 2.0, options QFlagsQSurfaceFormat::FormatOption(), depthBufferSize -1, redBufferSize -1, greenBufferSize -1, blueBufferSize -1, alphaBufferSize -1, stencilBufferSize -1, samples -1, swapBehavior QSurfaceFormat::SwapBehavior(DefaultSwapBehavior), swapInterval 1, profile QSurfaceFormat::OpenGLContextProfile(NoProfile))
qt.qpa.gl: Basic wglCreateContext gives version 3.1
qt.qpa.gl: OpenGL 2.0 entry points available
qt.qpa.gl: GPU features: QSet("disable_desktopgl")
qt.qpa.gl: Disabling Desktop GL: GpuDescription(vendorId=0x8086, deviceId=0x102, subSysId=0x2abf103c, revision=9, driver: "igdumd64.dll", version=9.17.10.4459, "Intel(R) HD Graphics")
qt.qpa.gl: QWindowsOpenGLTester::supportedRenderers GpuDescription(vendorId=0x8086, deviceId=0x102, subSysId=0x2abf103c, revision=9, driver: "igdumd64.dll", version=9.17.10.4459, "Intel(R) HD Graphics") renderer: QFlags(0x2|0x4|0x8|0x20)
qt.qpa.gl: Qt: Using EGL from libEGL
qt.qpa.gl: Qt: Using OpenGL ES 2.0 from libGLESv2
qt.qpa.gl: QWindowsEGLStaticContext::create Created EGL display 0x231e2bdc450 v 1 . 4
qt.qpa.gl: QWindowsIntegration::createPlatformOpenGLContext QSurfaceFormat(version 2.0, options QFlagsQSurfaceFormat::FormatOption(), depthBufferSize -1, redBufferSize -1, greenBufferSize -1, blueBufferSize -1, alphaBufferSize -1, stencilBufferSize -1, samples 0, swapBehavior QSurfaceFormat::SwapBehavior(DefaultSwapBehavior), swapInterval 1, profile QSurfaceFormat::OpenGLContextProfile(NoProfile))
qt.qpa.windows: QWindowsContext::registerWindowClass "Qt5QWindowOwnDCIcon" style=0x28 brush=0x1100060 icon=true atom=49819
qt.qpa.windows: QWindowsGeometryHint::frame style=0x86cf0000 exStyle=0x0 RECT: left/top=-8,-31 right/bottom=8,8 QMargins(8, 31, 8, 8)
qt.qpa.windows: QWindowCreationContext::QWindowCreationContext QWindow(0x231e53f99d0, name="QOffscreenSurface") QRect(0,0 1x1) pos incl. frame=false frame=17x40+0+0 min=QSize(0, 0) max=QSize(16777215, 16777215) custom margins=QMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
qt.qpa.windows: CreateWindowEx: QWindow(0x231e53f99d0, name="QOffscreenSurface") class="Qt5QWindowOwnDCIcon" title="MVM_UserInterface"
WindowCreationData: QFlagsQt::WindowType(Window|WindowTitleHint|WindowSystemMenuHint|WindowMinMaxButtonsHint|WindowCloseButtonHint)
topLevel=true popup=false dialog=false embedded=false tool=false
style=0x86cf0000 WS_POPUP WS_CLIPSIBLINGS WS_CLIPCHILDREN WS_THICKFRAME WS_DLGFRAME WS_SYSMENU WS_MINIMIZEBOX WS_MAXIMIZEBOX
requested: QRect(0,0 1x1): 17x40+0+0 custom margins: QMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
qt.qpa.windows: >QWindowsGeometryHint::applyToMinMaxInfo< min=0,0 max=16777215,16777215 in MINMAXINFO maxSize=1696,1066 maxpos=-8,-8 mintrack=136,39 maxtrack=1700,1070
qt.qpa.windows: QWindowsGeometryHint::frame style=0x86cf0000 exStyle=0x0 RECT: left/top=-8,-31 right/bottom=8,8 QMargins(8, 31, 8, 8)
qt.qpa.windows: <QWindowsGeometryHint::applyToMinMaxInfo frame=QMargins(8, 31, 8, 8) 16,39 out MINMAXINFO maxSize=1696,1066 maxpos=-8,-8 mintrack=136,39 maxtrack=1700,1070
qt.qpa.windows: CreateWindowEx: returns QWindow(0x231e53f99d0, name="QOffscreenSurface") 0x40c28 obtained geometry: QRect(8,31 120x1) QMargins(8, 31, 8, 8)
qt.qpa.windows: QWindowsIntegration::createPlatformWindow QWindow(0x231e53f99d0, name="QOffscreenSurface")
Requested: QRect(0,0 1x1) frame incl.=false QFlagsQt::WindowType(Window)
Obtained : QRect(8,31 120x1) margins=QMargins(8, 31, 8, 8) handle=0x40c28 QFlagsQt::WindowType(Window|WindowTitleHint|WindowSystemMenuHint|WindowMinMaxButtonsHint|WindowCloseButtonHint)

qt.qpa.mime: QWindowsWindow::setDropSiteEnabled QWindow(0x231e53f99d0, name="QOffscreenSurface") true
qt.qpa.mime: QWindowsOleDropTarget::QWindowsOleDropTarget 0x231e8043430 QWindow(0x231e53f99d0, name="QOffscreenSurface")
OpenGL error 00000502 - GL_INVALID_OPERATION, at C:\Projects\CodeFactory\Src\Apps\MVM_UserInterface\QtGui\MainGlWidget.cpp:88 - for glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
OpenGL error 00000502 - GL_INVALID_OPERATION, at C:\Projects\CodeFactory\Src\Apps\MVM_UserInterface\QtGui\MainGlWidget.cpp:89 - for glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE)
OpenGL error 00000502 - GL_INVALID_OPERATION, at C:\Projects\CodeFactory\Src\Apps\MVM_UserInterface\QtGui\MainGlWidget.cpp:93 - for glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH)
OpenGL error 00000502 - GL_INVALID_OPERATION, at C:\Projects\CodeFactory\Src\Apps\MVM_UserInterface\QtGui\MainGlWidget.cpp:94 - for glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)
OpenGL error 00000502 - GL_INVALID_OPERATION, at C:\Projects\CodeFactory\Src\Apps\MVM_UserInterface\QtGui\MainGlWidget.cpp:95 - for glEnable(GL_LIGHT0)
OpenGL error 00000502 - GL_INVALID_OPERATION, at C:\Projects\CodeFactory\Src\Apps\MVM_UserInterface\QtGui\MainGlWidget.cpp:96 - for glClearColor(0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 1)
OpenGL error 00000502 - GL_INVALID_OPERATION, at C:\Projects\CodeFactory\Src\Apps\MVM_UserInterface\QtGui\MainGlWidget.cpp:97 - for glEnable(GL_BLEND)
OpenGL error 00000502 - GL_INVALID_OPERATION, at C:\Projects\CodeFactory\Src\Apps\MVM_UserInterface\QtGui\MainGlWidget.cpp:98 - for glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
OpenGL error 00000502 - GL_INVALID_OPERATION, at C:\Projects\CodeFactory\Src\Apps\MVM_UserInterface\QtGui\MainGlWidget.cpp:99 - for glDepthMask(GL_TRUE)
failed to compile shader: Phong/Phong.frag
ERROR: 0:2: '' : No precision specified for (float)
```

In addition I add mainglwidget.cpp file for clarification

```
// MainGlWidget.cpp


#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtOpenGL>
#include "MainGlWidget.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "Common.h"
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <unistd.h>
#endif // 


/*#include "Common.h"
#include "UltimateDesign.h"*/

MainGlWidget::MainGlWidget(QWidget *parent)
: QOpenGLWidget(parent)
{
    xRot = 0;
    yRot = 0;
    zRot = 0;

}

MainGlWidget::~MainGlWidget()
{
}

QSize MainGlWidget::minimumSizeHint() const
{
    return QSize(50, 50);
}

QSize MainGlWidget::sizeHint() const
{
    return QSize(400, 400);
}

static void qNormalizeAngle(int &angle)
{
    while (angle < 0)
        angle += 360 * 16;
    while (angle > 360)
        angle -= 360 * 16;
}

void MainGlWidget::setXRotation(int angle)
{
    qNormalizeAngle(angle);
    if (angle != xRot) {
        xRot = angle;
        emit xRotationChanged(angle);

    }
}

void MainGlWidget::setYRotation(int angle)
{
    qNormalizeAngle(angle);
    if (angle != yRot) {
        yRot = angle;
        emit yRotationChanged(angle);
    }
}

void MainGlWidget::setZRotation(int angle)
{
    qNormalizeAngle(angle);
    if (angle != zRot) {
        zRot = angle;
        emit zRotationChanged(angle);
    }
}
void MainGlWidget::importFile(std::string file)
{

    makeCurrent();
    application->importFile(file);
    doneCurrent();

}

void MainGlWidget::initializeGL()
{

    CHECK_GL(glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST));
    CHECK_GL(glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE));

   //CHECK_GL(glCullFace(GL_CULL_FACE));
    //glCullFace(GL_BACK);
    CHECK_GL(glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH));
    CHECK_GL(glEnable(GL_LIGHTING));
    CHECK_GL(glEnable(GL_LIGHT0));
    CHECK_GL(glClearColor(0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 1));
    CHECK_GL(glEnable(GL_BLEND));
    CHECK_GL(glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA));
    CHECK_GL(glDepthMask(GL_TRUE));
#ifdef WIN32
    //glViewport(0, 0, 1280, 960);
#endif
    application->init((QOpenGLWidget*)this);
    application->setScreenDimentions(width(),height());

#ifdef WIN32
    CreateThread(
        NULL,                   // default security attributes
        0,                      // use default stack size
        timer,       // thread function name
        (void*) this,          // argument to thread function
        0,                      // use default creation flags
        NULL);  // returns the thread identifier
#elif __linux__ || __APPLE__
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, timer,    (void*) this);
#endif

}

void MainGlWidget::paintGL()
{
    GLint m_viewport[4];

    glGetIntegerv( GL_VIEWPORT, m_viewport );

    CHECK_GL(glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT));



    //std::cout<<"paint "<<pthread_self();


    application->render("cam1");
    //((Geo::Cube*)scene->get("cube2"))->draw();    
}

void MainGlWidget::resizeGL(int width, int height)
{
    std::cout << "width" << width << std::endl;
    std::cout << "height" << height << std::endl;
     size[0] = width;
     size[1] = height;
#ifndef DRONE
    int side = qMin(size[0], size[1]);
    glViewport((size[0]-side)/2,(size[1]-side)/2, side, side);
#endif
    update();
}

void MainGlWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    lastPos = event->pos();
    if (event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) {
    application->mouseClickWithLeft(lastPos.x(),lastPos.y());
    }else if (event->buttons() & Qt::RightButton) {
        application->mouseClickWithRight(lastPos.x(),lastPos.y());
    }
    //std::cout<<"clicked point 2D x,y"<<lastPos.x()<<","<<lastPos.y()<<std::endl;

}

void MainGlWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    int dx = event->x() - lastPos.x();
    int dy = event->y() - lastPos.y();
    lastPos = event->pos();
    if (event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) {
        setXRotation(xRot + dy);
        setYRotation(yRot + dx);
        application->mouseDragWithLeft(dx,dy);
    } else if (event->buttons() & Qt::RightButton) {
        setXRotation(xRot + 8 * dy);
        setZRotation(zRot + 8 * dx);
        application->mouseDragWithRight(dx,dy);
    }else if (event->buttons() &Qt::MiddleButton) {
        setXRotation(xRot + 8 * dy);
        setZRotation(zRot + 8 * dx);
        application->mouseDragWithMiddle(dx,dy);
    }





//  float rot[] = { xRot, 0, 0 };
//  float transc[] = { 0, 0, 1 }; 
//  scene->getCamera("cam1")->setTransformation(transc, rot);
//  scene->updated=true;
//    scene->callViews();
}

void MainGlWidget::draw()
{

}
#ifdef WIN32

DWORD WINAPI timer(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    MainGlWidget* glwidget = (MainGlWidget*)lpParam;

    while (true)
    {

        glwidget->update();

        Sleep(10);
    }


}
#elif __linux__ || __APPLE__

void *timer(void *lpParam)
{
    MainGlWidget* glwidget = (MainGlWidget*)lpParam;

    while (true)
    {

        glwidget->update();
        usleep(16000);

    }

}
#endif
```

Comment: Is `MainGlWidget.cpp` one of your classes? Looks to me as if you would be calling OpenGL commands from a method that does not have an OpenGL Context.

Comment: The same code works in other windows machines and MacOSx enviroments however just incase I added MainGlWidget.cpp to my question for your reference.

Comment: Do you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Look at this lines:

> qt.qpa.gl: GPU features: QSet("disable_desktopgl")
>
> qt.qpa.gl: Disabling Desktop GL: GpuDescription(vendorId=0x8086,
> deviceId=0x102, subSysId=0x2abf103c, revision=9, driver:
> "igdumd64.dll", version=9.17.10.4459, "Intel(R) HD Graphics")

It says that desktop OpenGL is banned on this graphics card, so Angle context is created. But yours OpenGL code is not GLES 2.0 code, so it is not working.
You could override graphics check via setting this attribute:

```
QApplication::setAttribute( Qt::AA_UseDesktopOpenGL );
```

It should be set before QApplication is created.
https://www.qt.io/blog/2014/11/27/qt-weekly-21-dynamic-opengl-implementation-loading-in-qt-5-4